# Bootstrap collapse / accordion doesn't stay open on Firefox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the Bootstrap accordion collapse to work properly on Firefox. If I click on the accordion title, it shows the content for a second but doesn't stay open. I also tried it with "toggle" : "hidden", but that didn't work either. Any feedback or help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<head>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>  
   <script>  
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".collapse").collapse({"toggle" : "show"});
        });
   </script> 
</head>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
     <div class="accordion-heading">
       <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"  href="#collapseOne">Example</a>
     </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
     <div class="accordion-inner"> Example text for the accordion...</div>
   </div>
  </div> 
</div><!--end of accordion-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add data-toggle and data-parent attributes bootstrap initializes accordion automatically.
I think you just need to remove javascript initialiation - $(".collapse").collapse({"toggle" : "show"});

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already used `"toggle" : "show"`, you need to remove class `in` of your accordion:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3434/)**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Unfortunately, I still didn't get it to work on Firefox. When I try it on localhost it works fine, but on my live site it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I removed also the

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
```

from the

```
<head>
```

and now it works!